# How can I install stack on ARM64?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

Since I'm using Gentoo ARM 64 bit on Raspberry Pi 4, I couldn't install stack according to https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/.

So I downloaded GHC 8.2.2 and installed it on my Raspi 4. Then I managed to get Cabal running. When I try to install stack by entering the command:

```
./cabal install stack
```

After a while the installation fails and throws the following error:

```
/tmp/cabal-install.-28208/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-28208/stack-2.1.3.1/dist/setup/setup.hs:6:42:
error:
Module ‘Distribution.Package’ does not export ‘InstalledPackageId’
  |
6 | import Distribution.Package ( PackageId, InstalledPackageId, packageVersion, packageName )
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/tmp/cabal-install.-28208/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-28208/stack-2.1.3.1/dist/setup/setup.hs:8:60:
error:
Module ‘Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo’
does not export ‘installedPackageId’
  |
8 | import Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo (sourcePackageId, installedPackageId)
  |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/tmp/cabal-install.-28208/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-28208/stack-2.1.3.1/dist/setup/setup.hs:10:36:
error:
Module ‘Distribution.Simple.Utils’ does not export ‘rewriteFile’
   |
10 | import Distribution.Simple.Utils ( rewriteFile, createDirectoryIfMissingVerbose )
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^

/tmp/cabal-install.-28208/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-28208/stack-2.1.3.1/dist/setup/setup.hs:11:41:
error:
Module ‘Distribution.Simple.BuildPaths’
does not export ‘autogenModulesDir’
   |
11 | import Distribution.Simple.BuildPaths ( autogenModulesDir )
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/tmp/cabal-install.-28208/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-28208/stack-2.1.3.1/dist/setup/setup.hs:18:31:
error:
Module ‘Distribution.Version’ does not export ‘showVersion’
   |
18 | import Distribution.Version ( showVersion )
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

On [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/fjkfd4/how_to_install_stack_on_openbsd/) I found a possible solution. Isn't there however an easier solution to this problem? Will it work on Raspi 4, too? Because for the operating system Raspbian there is a stack Version available. But I don't want to use this operating system.

I'd like to continue developing my website on the Raspi 4 using yesod or snap so that I can make money with it. Because my main computer is still in a self storage in Germany but I live in Italy now.

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't want to spend lots of time with configuring and installing something. So I just downloaded a package which was suitable for my architecture from Arch. Then I unpacked it and put in my home directory.

The stack packages can be found here:
[Arch Linux Repo](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/stack-bin/)

You also need to export the path to the stack binary so that other programs can find stack on your system:

```
$ export PATH="${PATH}:/home/user/.local/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

The packages on arch (reference above) is not available.
I tried to install -- for a raspi4 (64bit arm64 architecture) -- and failed miserably. I installed with `apt` from the debian repositories `apt install haskell-stack` and then run `stack upgrade` which made me to install further `llvm-11, libtinfo-5, opt` but ended with an error: `could not execute: opt`
I am surprised that `haskell-stack` is not available for the popular (Raspberry 4) arm64 platform!